# GPS coordinate on mousechange event

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I have a FLutter web app using google_maps_flutter.

I would like to add a listener that returns the GPS coordinates on mouse change event.
I have the following that works for mouse click. I need something similar but on mouse chenge

```html
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GoogleMap(
      onTap: (LatLng latLng) {
        final lat = latLng.latitude;
        final long = latLng.longitude;
        print(lat);
        print(long);
      },
      onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
      initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(47.38445, 8.546780),
        zoom: 10,
      ),
      myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
      zoomControlsEnabled: false,
      compassEnabled: false,
      mapType: MapType.normal,
      polylines: Set<Polyline>.from(_polylines),
    );
  }
```

Comment: you're looking for the 'mousemove' event of the Map object. But I don't know how you register such listeners in Flutter...